# Commands underlined in express/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image] Any idea, why require is underlined here? Got something similar in my React front-end and tests. Some commands were underlined but the code worked as expected.

Tried npm install --save-dev @types/express but that didn't help much.

Thanks

Comment: What does it say when you hover over `require`?

Comment: Images should always be added to the question, so it can be viewed w/o clicking a link.

Answer (score 1):

**On the button right corner of Vcode Please make sure it is javascript instead of typescript**

[image]